# A word or phrase replacing "As I was warning you earlier"

Tags: phrases

As indicated in the title, I would like to replace what's in the
parentheses in the following example with an amusing phrase:

> You expected event A to happen.
>
> (But as I was warning you earlier), instead, event B took place.

Comment: Instead, event B occured as I predicted (*or anticipated*).

Comment: Please do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). They are out of scope and your question may be removed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  Phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research. [(more¹)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [(more²)](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) [(more³)](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/3226/14073)

Answer (score 2):

> You expected event A to happen.
>
> **I hate to say I told you so, :-) but**, instead, event B took place.

The **:-)** is optional, but it enhances the humor.

By the way, you should replace "As I was warning you earlier" with "As I warned you earlier", given that event B occurred after you providing the warning, not while you were providing it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, "As I warned you earlier." or "As I cautioned you earlier." (Or perhaps "previously".

It's less passive and to the point.  Colloquially, it's, "I told you that was going to happen,"

Comment: We appreciate the desire to help, but please consider either expanding your answer or deleting it. Questions should be answered as an expert would answer them: comprehensively, with explanation and context. Explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Unsupported answers may be removed. [(more¹)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post) [(more²)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166566/lots-of-not-always-useful-but-well-intentioned-answers)